# “Controlled by” vs. “Control by”

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, prepositional-passive

We usually use the past participle to indicate passive.

Why the rule doesn’t apply to “control”

[The Source](http://www.discourses.org/OldArticles/Power%20and%20the%20news%20media.pdf)

> - This suggests that mind **control** by the media should be particularly effective when the media users do not realize...
>
> Why isn’t it like: ........mind controlled by the media....

Comment: Because the meaning will be completely different, and in this case it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Mind control" (also called ["brainwashing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainwashing)) is a [compound noun](https://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/nouncompound.html), like "bed frame" or "swimming pool".  It is the subject of the phrase, and not "mind" by itself -- the sentence says that this *technique*, practiced by the media, is effective under certain conditions.

(Note:  "mind control" also refers to the direct control of some person by some external entity (like someone with special mental powers) and is a popular subject in fiction.)

If you wanted to use the passive verb, with "mind" as the subject, you could say:

> The study shows that **the minds controlled** by the media (are more likely to buy on impulse and prefer products they've seen advertised.)

It would be unusual to refer to *people* as "minds" but not out-of-place with the right context.

Comment: Well explained, I didn’t know that control is a noun here. And makes with “mind” a compound noun.